# Pointer to pointer gives segmentation fault?

Tags: c

Here is the code

```
    int main
    {
    char s[]="prady";
    char **p;

    p=(char **)&s;

    printf("%u %u\n",p,*p);
    printf("%u %u\n",&s,s); 

    printf("%s\n",s);
    printf("%s\n",&s);
    printf("%u %u\n",s+1,&s+1);


    printf("%s\n",p);
    printf("%s\n",*p);
    }
```

o/p:

```
3217062327 1684107888
3217062327 3217062327
prady
prady
3217062328 3217062336
prady
Segmentation fault
```

My doubt as follows

1. How both the address is same of s and &s?
2. If both are same then how they show different when adding 1 to it?
3. How I got segmentation fault in *p?

Comment: Use `%p\n` to print an address.

Comment: You need to understand that arrays are handled ironically in C.

Comment: @Hot-:Thanks for your answer:What do you mean by arrays are handled ironically ,can you explain a bit more.

Comment: No matter how you think arrays work, ironically you will be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

First, arrays are not pointers. Pointers are not arrays. Arrays **decay** into pointers.

`1.How both the address is same of s and &s?`

```
char s[]="prady";

   --------------------------
s: | p | r | a | d | y | \0 |
   --------------------------
```

The array `s` is a request for 6 characters to be set aside. In other words, at `s` there are 6 characters. 's` is a "thing", it doesn't point at anything, it just is.

```
char *ptr = "prady";

------         --------------------------
|*ptr|    -->  | p | r | a | d | y | \0 |
------         --------------------------
```

The pointer `ptr` requests a place which holds a pointer. The pointer can point at any char or any string literal (continuous chars).

Another way to think about this:

```
int b;   //this is integer type 
&b;      //this is the address of the int b, right?  

int c[]; //this is the array of ints 
&c;      //this would be the address of the array, right?
```

So that's pretty understandable how about this:

```
*c;   //that's the first element in the array
```

What does that line of code tell you? if I deference c, then I get an int. That means just plain c is an address. Since it's the start of the array it's the address of the array, thus:

```
c == &c;
```

`2. If both are same then how they show different when adding 1 to it.`

From my answer to #1 I assume you see why they're not the same. So why do you get different values?
Look at the values you get:

```
s    = 0x3217062327 
s+1  = 0x3217062328  // It's 1 bigger, why? Because a char takes 1 byte, s holds chars
                     // so s (address of a char) + 1 (sizeof char) gives you one more than s
&a + 1 //This is adding 1 (sizeof array) which is bigger than the size of a char
```

`3. How I got segmentation fault in *p.`

I think you can get this from my previous two answers...
But:

1. p is a pointer to a pointer to a character
2. You set p to the address of the array (which remember, is the array itself)
3. a deference of p is a pointer to a char (another address), however you can't do that to the array.

When you typecast you tell the compiler "I know better then you so just make these two work". When you segfault... it's because you didn't really know better.

Comment: Thanks mike for your valuable answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your case s isn't a pointer. It is an array!

a small change will fix a thing:

```
char *s = "prady";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but which one your are given the answer for.

Comment: But arrays are nothing but a const pointer internally as I know,can you tell more on this.

Comment: It's the answer to all of them. Auto-magic conversion of arrays into pointers is a dark secret of C. One primer is here: http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/a-tutorial-on-pointers-and-arrays-in-c-r1697

Comment: This is wrong. Array may be treated as pointer but not always.

Comment: 'arrays are nothing but a const pointer internally' -- certainly not; when an array is given where a pointer is expected, the address of the first element of the array is used ... but that doesn't make an array a pointer. An array is an aggregate of same-typed values and has a size which is the sum of the sizes of those values; a pointer is not an aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.How both the address is same of s and &s.

`s` is an array of characters. But, arrays are converted to pointers, save in a few cases: when they are used to initialize an array (e.g: your `char s[]="prady";`
 line), when they are the operand of the unary `&` operator (plenty of cases in your code), and when they are the operand of the `sizeof` operator.

> 2.If both are same then how they show different when adding 1 to it.

They are not the same.

> 2.How I got segmentation fault in *p.

`p` contains the address of `"prady"`. `*p` contains `"prady"`. Attempting to use `"prady"` as if it were the address of a string causes a segfault.

Comment: Thanks for the answer:I have the same doubt if both are not same then how they are showing same address and what is the relation between the pointer conversion to this as if p is a pointer then p and &p both are different,but here it is  same how.